# Multivariate outlier detection for PLS model

Tags: multivariate-analysis, prediction, outliers, partial-least-squares

I am working with a PLS model (library pls) in R, where I am developing calibration models for NIRS data. I have been using other commercial software before that allowed me to detect outliers based on Mahalanobis distances.

However, although R has proven to be superior in all senses to any software I have used before, I cannot find a good way of detecting potential outliers in a new dataset to be predicted.
my model follows the structure:

```
model<-plsr(as.matrix(dataset)~constituent, CV=TRUE, ncomp=15)
```

And then I predict:

```
predictions<-predict(model, newdata=NEWDATA,ncomp=15)
```

But how can I assess the fitness of the predictions?

When I try to apply the "mahalanobis" command from {stats}, I do the following:

```
mahalanobis.data<-mahalanobis(new-dataset,colMeans(dataset),var(dataset))
```

And either R crashes, or gives error messages. I have tried also with some of the rrcovHD and mvoutlier commands, but I suddenly get half of my dataset detected as outlier.

Since I have n< p, conventional multivariate outlier detection does not apply here, as far as I am concerned.

Is there any package I have overlooked, or something I am not applying properly?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, I mixed the > and < signs, sorry. Now I fixed it in the question also. The message I get is: Error in covMcd(X) : n <= p -- you can't be serious! (which, of course, is a logical message to get)

Comment: and what is $n$ and $p$? Also, are all your variable continuous? Are all your cases complete or do you have missing cells in some rows?

Comment: My variables are 2100 columns with absorbance values from a NIRS spectrometer, with no missing cells and no zero values. 
As for n= number of observations and p= parameters (i.e. n=rows, p=columns)

Comment: Typically, people use robust PCA method for this type of data. There are a couple of approaches in the rrcov library. Have you tried those?

Comment: Yes, I have used both rrcov and rrcovHD libraries: using PCAHubert() from the first, or OutlierPCOut() from the second. Although I get outlier estimation from the training set, I cannot use that model to estimate outliers from the test set. And I did not find the solutions in the documentation either. That is why I suspect I am not using the right approach...

Comment: OK, Im starting to understand the problem better. I will send more info/questions your way.

Comment: Hi, and sorry for bothering you. Any progress?
I have tried to find a workaround to apply Mahalanobis distances based on the wavelengths which have highest loadings, but that is not a robust way to do it either (although it detects my suspected outliers...). 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: good, I was looking for this quesiton couldn t find it anymore. I will draft a short 'answer' that will be more about links.

Comment: Thanks! Just to save you some time: I have used the mahalanobis() command in the next way: mahalanobis(x0,colMeans(x0),cov(x0),inverted=TRUE), where x0 is the reference matrix. I can of course apply the same to x1 (new dataset). 
I get M-distances ONLY when I add the inverted=TRUE, but I am not sure what does the "inverted" do in practice. I am working in the right direction? Thanks again!